# What algorithms can I use to produce simple human-readable fault-tolerant strings?

Tags: algorithm, search, fault-tolerance, fuzzy-comparison

Humans make mistakes. 
When you require them to provide some unique generated ID identifying some entity.
For example:
 Order A: has id ABC1234
 Order B: has id BCD1235
They can make typos, they can provide string for ex: A123, B123, 1 2 3, "Order id B 12/3"
Then for automatic system its a challenge to identify the original ID.
My questions is are there any known algorithms/techniques. To generate a

-unique human readable ID (not sha or md5)
-with fault tolerance. That you can from a subset of character still decode the original id. 
-case insensitive

A visual example of fault tolerance are QR codes, when some part of qr code damaged you can still read the message.

The goals is to avoid tools/algorithms like for ex. elastic search,  levenstein and increase the chance to decode the original id even when the customer makes a typo, and reduce the chance that some other "original id" will be provided.

Comment: needs some adaptation for the task, but it's a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_detection_and_correction

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Are there any know algorithms, which produce simple human readable string. Which with added redundancy will be fault tolerant for human errors/typos.

Comment: **See also**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761898

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=diceware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from error correction, the interesting part of this question is whether there are codes designed specifically for humans to read and transcribe.

In [RFC 3548](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3548.html), some considerations are made for avoiding the use of easily-confused characters in base32 coding (1 and L, 0 and o). [Human-oriented base-32 encoding](http://philzimmermann.com/docs/human-oriented-base-32-encoding.txt) has some variations on that concept.

For audio, the [PGP Word List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGP_word_list) is designed to give each byte a distinct word; it helps to protect against errors by having two lists of 256 words, one used for even bytes, the other for odd bytes (so a missing byte or swapped bytes can be detected).

There was [a discussion here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761898/how-to-generate-a-human-friendly-unique-id-in-python) about human friendly, pronounceable IDs which might be interesting, work on pronounceable passwords (like [Diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware)) is somewhat related.

Metafilter also had [a discussion](http://ask.metafilter.com/249447/Encoding-for-transcription) about codes that are easy for humans to copy that provides a few more interesting references.